# Referencing to a particular table's th, tr, and td

Tags: html, css

I have two tables on my site, those are named:

```
<table class="table1">

<table class="table2">
```

I am trying to reference to `table1`'s `td`, `tr` and `th` using:

```
table.table1 td, tr, th {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

but it applied to both my tables and I can't overwrite the styling to `table2`. What went wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The commas in between each selector means *a new selector*. So the `tr` and `th` selector are generic to all tables and not just `table1`. So you need to specify `table1` for each of those selector .

```
table.table1 td, table.table1 tr, table.table1 th {
```

Comment: Terminology correction: the commas separate *selectors* here, not rules. The entire construct is a CSS rule, with three selectors.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
table.table1 td, table.table1 tr, table.table1 th {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

You must access `tr`, `th` through parents only if you want to apply particular style, every rule is separated by comma. You must reference the parent's class to apply style to `tr`, `td` childs

You applied css style to all `tr`, `th` from page.

Comment: You should explain why this works, as @John Conde done.